# Questions regarding OpenSSL

Tags: discussion, scope

I don't see a unified policy regarding this. I saw questions regarding OpenSSL on Stack Overflow. Also, I've asked a question regarding OpenSSL on Information Security Stack Exchange. It was moved to Server Fault. So I'm really confused over the matter. I would simply like to get answers without spamming.

[This is from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl/27931596#27931596). It wasn't flagged.

[This is mine,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789341/openssl-generate-crl-yields-the-error-unable-to-get-issuer-keyiid?noredirect=1#comment70788442_41789341) which was flagged as off-topic.

Comment: FWIW, *one* such vote in ~24 hours does not an official policy make one way or the other. That's why votes by 5 different users are required…

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer #deceze (I suppose you could make it as an answer)

Comment: I'd prefer for an [tag:openssl] expert to weigh in and offer their opinion on how *programming related* this is exactly. I'd say it's okay, but I have little experience with the particular process you're attempting there. It may or may not be more ServerFault related, I cannot say.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not convinced it could be terribly programming related @deceze.  This is more firmly in the realm of DevOps and server administration; a programming-esque question regarding OpenSSL might be how to use it in a shell script or a shell-like script, but even then it's still DevOps-y.

Comment: @Makoto a squarely programming question would be "How to encrypt my data stream in C using blowfish?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to use the OpenSSL libraries/headers to develop software, that would be a question for Stack Overflow (baring other limitations), as most of those questions are done by people that are programmers, while they are programming.

The mere use of the openssl binary isn't a programming question per-se. If you can find yourself asking this question, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/792066) where you could easily be a programmer, a webmaster, postmaster, or private user, that isn't a programming question.

Creating certificates isn't something unique to software development. Case point: I had to create certificates for a personal OpenVPN server, I didn't write a single line of code while doing this and followed a very [user oriented](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Easy-RSA) guide. I didn't had to install development headers, nor compilers, nor read language specifications while I was doing this task. It was, strictly speaking, something not unique to software development.

Comment: You can replace OpenSSL with any other library/binary combo (libav, curl, polkit, gtk, etc.) and it would be the same.

Comment: Thank you. So, the reason I see this kind of questions on stack overflow is because not enough people have payed attention to them.